# Creating a tkinter quick multiplication game using recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tkinter

I'm trying to create a game that generates 2 random numbers and then the user has to type the correct answer of the product of it, then 1 point is gained. I'm trying to get it to stop once it's been done 10 times however I can't seem to get it to end. I tried using a loop rather than recursion but I also got stuck on that.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random

numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
qm_score = 0
global recursion_count
recursion_count = 0
quickmulti_page = tk.Tk()
quickmulti_page.title =("Quick multiplication")
quickmulti_page.config(background="SlateGray1")
quickmulti_page.geometry("300x200")

def endgame():
    print("Youre done")
    print(qm_score)

def multiplication():
    def multi_answer(event):
        recursion_count = recursion_count + 1
        if recursion_count == 10:
            if user_answer == answer:
                qm_score = qm_score + 1
                endgame()
            else:
                endgame()
        elif recursioncount > 3:
            multiplication()
        else:
            endgame()

        
    num1 = random.choice(numbers)
    num2 = random.choice(numbers)
    answer = num1 * num2
    qlabel = Label(quickmulti_page, text=(num1,"x", num2), font=100, width=20, height=3).place(x=50,y=40)
    user_answer = Entry(quickmulti_page,width=30)
    user_answer.place(x=50, y=120)
    user_answer.bind('<Return>', multi_answer)
```

Comment: You know that calling `multiplication` isn't going to do a thing, right? It just defines a function without calling it so it is useless

Comment: why do You define a function inside a function anyways?